# $f_*: H_*(S^n, \mathbb{Z}_p) \to H_*(M, \mathbb{Z}_p)$ an isomorphism if $p$ is a prime that does not divide $q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a compact connected $n$-manifold (without boundary), where $n \ge 2$. Suppose $M$ is oriented with fundamental class $z$. Let $f: S^n \to M$ be a map such that $f_*(i_n) = qz$ where $i_n \in H_n(S^n, \mathbb{Z})$ is the fundamental class and $q \neq 0$. Is $f_*: H_*(S^n, \mathbb{Z}_p) \to H_*(M, \mathbb{Z}_p)$ an isomorphism if $p$ is a prime that does not divide $q$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true.  Let us first consider $H_n$.  The natural map $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p\to H_n(X,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is an isomorphism for $X=S^n$ and $X=M$.  We thus have the following commutative diagram, where the vertical maps are isomorphisms:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{Z}_p @>{f_*\otimes 1}>> H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p\\
@V{}VV @V{}VV \\
H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z}_p) @>{f_*}>> H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)
\end{CD}$$

By assumption, the top map is multiplication by $q$, when we identify $H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ using $i_n$ and $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ using $z$.  Since $q$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, this means the top map is an isomorphism.  Thus the bottom map is also an isomorphism.

Now for $0<*<n$, we can show $f_*:H_*(S^n,\mathbb{Z})\to H_*(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is an isomorphism by showing that $H_*(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is trivial.  To show this, it suffices to show $H^*(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is trivial.  Suppose $a\in H^*(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is nonzero.  Then by Poincaré duality, there exists $b\in H^{n-*}(M,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ such that $ab\neq 0$.  But $f^*(a)=0$ since $H^*(S^n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is trivial, so $f^*(ab)=0$.  This is a contradiction, since $f$ induces an isomorphism on $H_n$ and hence also on $H^n$.

Comment: What about the $f_*$ on lower homologies?

Comment: Good question!  Apparently I never noticed the question was asking about the homology in all degrees.  I've added an explanation for lower degrees.